# Java android show dialog instead fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to get a tablout with 4 tabs . First 3 tabs should open a fragment but 4 should open a Dialog. I try do this :

```
String[] tabs = {"", "", "", ""};
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
viewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabs));

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(position == 3){
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        CommonUtil.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
        if(position == 3){
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});

tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

But always I get a fragment

Comment: You can try Using a `DialogFragment` at 4th place ..Or you can just add a blank frragment and show dialog when position is 3. . Apart from that `OnPageChangeListener` is just a callback it does not handles the `Adapter` ..

Comment: @ADM in getItem i have a fragment and herte I have a probleme to fo this